# doubt regarding calibration

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery

I have white MacBook (early 2009), with Snow Leopard running.

I read this following article about calibration: http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/9036.html

I have doubt in step 2
It says "*Allow the battery to rest in the fully charged state for two hours or longer.*", with subnote as "*You can use your computer during this time as long as the power adapter is plugged in.*"

**If I don't want to use computer after fully charging it, should I turn off and remove MagSafe Power Adapter or should I keep it on for 2 hours?**

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the magsafe in for 2 hours, whether it's on or sleeping.